# Excel VBA userform open hyperlink with a button

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I have a userform which I input information into, one of the inputs are called webpage and I want to open the webpage for each item I input into the userform when I click a command button.

```
Sheets("Data").Range("DataStart").Offset(TargetRow, 10).Value = Webpage

MyForm.Webpage = Sheets("Data").Range("DataStart").Offset(TargetRow, 10).Value
```

I am trying to use follow.hyperlink

```
Private Sub Webpage_Click()

Dim webpage As String
Set webpage = MyForm.Webpage = Sheets("Data").Range("DataStart").Offset(TargetRow, 10).Value

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="webpage"

End Sub
```

This doesn´t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=webpage
```

no quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Shell to open a specific browser, if required:

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()
Dim browserPath As String
Dim linkURL As String

browserPath = Environ("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
linkURL = Cells(1, 1).Value

Shell browserPath & " -url " & linkURL
End Sub
```